# How do I control whether Visual Studio Publish operation does a Rebuild or Build

Tags: visual-studio

When I right click on my solution in Solution Explorer and choose "Publish..." the resulting screen does not allow me to specify whether I want Visual Studio to do a Rebuild or a Build when it builds the project during the publish operation.  Is there a way to control this?  I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: This is set in the publish profile. Edit the profile and you have access to those options.

Comment: @fnostro yeah, I had checked that.  However, I don't see that option available in the publish profile screen.  I also looked directly in the .pubxml file, and don't see it there either.  It doesn't appear that this can be specified as far as I can tell.

Comment: "Build" means to compile conditionally and only compile things that have changed, "Rebuild" means to ignore unchanged files and compile everything regardless. And "Clean" means to delete files before building. So the wording might look different in the profile dialogs.